# How do I randomize responses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nltk

I am using NLTK to create a chatbot in Python but I am considering rewriting it for spaCy. I am looking for a way to feed my AI several pre-built sentences to choose from at random from the pairs when responding to a user.

For example; say the bot says something and the user asks “would you like to discuss that?” I want it to choose between “yes please!” and “no thank you!” at random.

My code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
import random
nltk.download("punkt")


pairs = [

 (
     r"I am satisfied with my care|quit",
     ["Bye, take care. See you soon!"]
 ),
 (
     r"would you like to discuss that?",
     ["no Thank you.", ]
 ),
 (
     r"hi|hello",
     ["Hello what is your name?", ]
 ),
 (
     r"my name is (.*)",
     ["Hello %1, how can I help you today?", ]
 ),
 (
     r"what is your name?",
     ["My name is ZeroBot and I'm here to help you.", ]
 ),
 (
     r"how are you?",
     ["I'm doing well, thank you!", ]
 ),
 (
     r"sorry (.*)",
     ["It's alright, no problem.", ]
 ),
 (
     r"(.*)",
     ["Hello %1, how can I help you today?", ]
 ),
 (
     r"what are you doing",
     ["I am talking to you.", ]
 ),

]


chatbot = Chat(pairs, reflections)


def chat():
 print("Hi, I'm ZeroBot. How can I help you today? Type 'I am satisfied with my care' to exit.")
 while True:
     user_input = input("You: ")
     response = chatbot.respond(user_input)
     print("ZeroBot:", response)
     if user_input.lower == "I am satisfied with my care":
         break
 
     if user_input.lower == "would you like to discuss that?":
         random_value = random.randint(1, 2)
         match random_value:
             case 1:
                 print("yes please!")
             case 2:
                 print("no thank you!")


chat()
```

Comment: Python has a respectable [library of random functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html). It's certainly up to the task of generating a random index for a list of responses, or shuffling responses and iterating if you want to avoid redundancies. You need to supply more details in order for people here to understand your needs.

Comment: @pjs I do apologise i was out at the time i wrote this and didn’t have direct access to my code to add to the post. i wrote this from my phone 

Answer (score 2):

Use the `random` module, which is a standard library (you don't have to install it).

Here is how to use it:

```
import random
if (your if statement):
    random_value = random.randint(1, 2)
    match random_value:
        case 1:
            print(“yes please!”)
        case 2:
            print(“no thank you!”)
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get your fix working , I have included my code in an edit to the question with your suggestion, may you please tell me where I am going wrong? (it is still defaulting to the response in pairs every time)

Comment: @DanniKurisu Could you please tell me what more specifically is going on? Is it printing an error?

Comment: @DanniKurisu The script that I used works, you can try it alone by simply removing the if statement. Could it be because your if statement does not work?

Comment: my original if statement works for breaking code the additional if statement doesn't :(

Comment: rather than spitting either response at random its favouring the response in pairs 100% of the time

Comment: @DanniKurisu that is really strange. could you please add a 'print(random_value)' after the 'random_value = random.randint(1, 2)' line?

Comment: same result. would it help if I sent a full pastebin of my code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qBCnuaaV

Comment: @DanniKurisu could you say me what it is printing out?

Comment: when I type to the bot "do you want to discuss this" it is spitting "no thank you" every time

Comment: @DanniKurisu I meant with the 'print(random_value)'

Comment: thats the thing it doesnt even attempt to like the pair is overriding it, I could just remove the pair and try that?

Comment: nope removing the pair did not work , it just confused the AI

Comment: @DanniKurisu but what is printed out? (the number)

Comment: a number isn't being printed out that's the issue, My NLTK bot code is overriding the random if statement

Comment: ```
        if user_input.lower == "would you like to discuss that?":
            random_value = random.randint(1, 2)
            print(random_value)
            match random_value:
                case 1:
                    print("yes please!")
                case 2:
                    print("no thank you!")
```

Comment: @DanniKurisu Since I dont know, I asked DeepAI. Does this help you? "You are missing parentheses after .lower in the if statement. It should be user_input.lower() to call the method and compare it to the string "would you like to discuss that?". 

Here is the corrected code:

if user_input.lower() == "would you like to discuss that?":"

Comment: adding that parenthesis did not make any changes but let me try  asking deep AI

Comment: I got the code partially working , nut i get extra strings in the form of "y" or "n" when attempting the prompt

Comment: @DanniKurisu So, does my answer work? Do you still need help from me?